# Extract image from a Discord message

Tags: python, discord, bots

I have written a code that should get an image from a message in a Discord and save it as an image.

However, when I try to run the program, I get an error.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\ExtractImage.py", line 6, in <module>
    client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'
```

Code:

```
from discord.ext import commands
import uuid
import requests
import shutil

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')

def send_discord_message():
    url = "https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/1095975130758393868/messages"
    payload = {
        'content': "/generate description:world"
    }
    header = {
        'authorization': 'token'
    }
    requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=header)


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready")


@client.command()
async def save(ctx):
    try:
        url = ctx.message.attachments[0].url
    except IndexError:
        print("Error: No attachments")
        await ctx.send("No attachments detected!")
    else:
        if url[0:26] == "https://cdn.discordapp.com":
            r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
            imageName = str(uuid.uuid4()) + '.jpg'
            with open(imageName, 'wb') as out_file:
                print('Saving image: ' + imageName)
                shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, out_file)

client.run('-')
```

I would appreciate an answer because I am stuck.

Comment: "I would appreciate an answer because I am stuck." Did you try [copying and pasting the error message into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=TypeError%3A+__init__()+missing+1+required+keyword-only+argument%3A+%27intents%27)?